# Detect when call, mic, or location banners pop up - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

Is there a listening function that will allow you to adjust a view's layout when a banner pops up at the top? (i.e. the banners that say "touch to return to call", "recording", "maps is using your location", etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should call your `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` method. You can override and adjust the view accordingly as per the view bounds. More info here

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621437-viewwilllayoutsubviews

Swift code:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        // Use self.view.bounds to do what you want to

    }
```

Objective C code:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // use self.view.bounds to do what you want to
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have all my subviews act as if the new bounds are the entire screen?

Comment: you meant automatically adjust to new bounds?

Comment: Right, all of my subviews right now are positioned based on UIScreen.main.bounds. Should I just replace that with self.view.bounds?

Comment: view.bounds will change as per the changes in view like navigation bar etc. so ideally you should use that.